# Gradient of a scalar field and directional derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I was solving the following exercise, and I became confused as to what is the difference between the two cases?

We are given a scalar valued function (scalar field) $f(x,y)= x^2y $ and a point B=(3,2)

First I am asked the max.change. That is simply the gradient, which is a vector whose direction points towards the greatest change and absolute value shows the value of this change in this particular direction.

I easily fint $\nabla f(x,)=(12,9)^T$ (T for vertical notation) and it's value is 15.

Then on a second question I am asked to find the directional derivative in $\vec u$ which is the normalized vector that shows the direction of the biggest change (in other words the gradient).

$\partial f/\partial\vec u|_B=15$.

What is the point of this second part? Isn't this a redundant thing?

I know that by doing the scalar product between the gradient of the scalar field and the normal vector of an arbitrary vector which points towards a direction, you will get the rate of change in that direction, when passing through a point B.

So how is the second part different then the first?

Comment: 'I easily find $\nabla f (x,) \dots$ and it's value is $15$' What value? You have a vector. Do you mean $\| \nabla f (3, 2) \| = 15$? Perhaps the question is asking which direction has the greatest rate of change, which would be the $x$ direction? Also, you never provided a vector $\vec{u}$ whose direction you are looking to compute the directional derivative along.

Comment: Like mattos said: "directional derivative in u⃗" doesn't parse in English.  I think you should back up and _define_   u⃗  .  I think they are trying to point out the mathematical operation of scalar gradient points in the same direction as the normal to f()=constant; just a guess.  In mathematics that attempts to capture external objective things, say manifolds, it is crucial to prove that all operations are "talking" about the object/manifold and not just about mathematics.  There are a lot of mathematical operations that don't.

Comment: An example: when modeling a manifold, f()=0, changing the coordinate system doesn't change the object under study, the manifold; it changes the description.